# Errno 13 Permission denied: 'train.zip' upon downloading data using Kaggle CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kaggle

I'm trying to download data from kaggle to my AWS p2.xlarge instance using Kaggle CLI. I've manually accepted the competition terms and conditions through the browser before trying to download data.  But I'm getting the error as shown below:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-9:~/courses/deeplearning1/nbs/data$ kg config -g -u 'username' -p 'password' -c 'dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition'                         

ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-9:~/courses/deeplearning1/nbs/data$ kg download                

downloading https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/download/test.zip                                                                       


test.zip N/A% |                                       | ETA:  --:--:--   0.0 s/B│
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.zip'
```

I upgraded CLI using pip install --upgrade kaggle-cli but got the same result. Any clues?

Comment: Do you have permission to write in the data directory?

Comment: My bad. I didn't have permission. I changed the permissions and was able to download. Thanks!